# Gatling results into console

Tags: report, performance-testing, gatling, messenger, scala-gatling

I want to print some of the Gatling results (for example, successful requests, 95% response time) into my cmd. Also I want to use these variables to pass them into my own report to send via mail or create messages in different messengers. Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it something you get out of the box?

[image]

If you want to see the code which generates the above lines - it's in [ConsoleTemplate](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/main/gatling-charts/src/main/scala/io/gatling/charts/template/ConsoleTemplate.scala)

If you need to build a custom report - Gatling parses its `simulation.log` file so it would be better to do it after the test as well. See [Using Gatling simulation log](https://www.keycloak.org/keycloak-benchmark/benchmark-guide/latest/report/simulationlog-report) page for example approach.

More information on Gatling: [8 Reasons You Should Use Gatling for Load Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/gatling-load-testing)